# How can Nginx force browsers to disable or flush the redirect cache?

Tags: nginx, redirect, 301-redirect

We have the following secure site. If the user opens `http://name.tld`, he should be redirected to `https://name.tld`. We initially messed up the order of the domains in the secure site, so `http://name.tld` got redirected to `https://sub.name.tld` instead of `http://name.tld`.

We changed the order of the server names, but all the browsers have that redirection cached. If I disable the cache in chrome manually, it works. But any other would need to do the same.

How can we force all browsers to clear their redirect cache (preferred) or disable tell them to not cache the redirect? Is there a header we can send?

This is our site:

```
server {
       listen         80;
       server_name    name.tld sub.name.tld localhost sub.localhost;
       return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen              443 ssl;
    server_name         name.tld sub.name.tld localhost sub.localhost;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/certs/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/privkey.pem;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

    # required for large JSON files
    client_max_body_size 50m;

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/log/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html/name.tld;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    location /api {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass http://our-api:5000/api;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

**Edit:** 
The actual connected issue with the redirect is CORS. Requests to the API fail because the requests would be made from a different domain.

Comment: You can't, because they already cached it!

Comment: Okay, what if I would change it to a 302 redirect?

Comment: That would just kill your SEO. It wouldn't do anything for the users who have the 301 cached.

Comment: I'd probably just set up a new redirect from the incorrect subdomain URL to the proper URL, and change the first incorrect redirect. I wouldn't worry about caching, everyone will end up at the right place and caches expire eventually.

Comment: Would there be a danger of a redirect loop (since the first redirect has been cached already?) Afaik, the chrome redirect cache will never expire by default if no cache headers have been set.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for us, specific to our case, is to enable CORS (see edit above) for requests from `https://sub.name.tld`. The people affected at least have a working web site under `https://sub.name.tld`